# how to save or update with object?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, upsert

I am writing code as follow to upsert mongodb:

```
def save_qs(self, qs)
    try:
        existed = QuerySetRecord.objects.get(recordId=qs.recordId)
        if qs.count > existed.count:
            qs._id = existed._id
            qs.save()
    except DoesNotExist as e:
        qs.save()
```

I find mongoengine check `_id` in `save` method, if obj has `_id`, do insert, update if not.

```
created = ('_id' not in doc or self._created or force_insert)
```

But I know this is not that good, how can I do better?

Here is the `QuerySet`:

```
class QuerySetRecord(Document):
    recordId = StringField(required=True)
    crawlerName = StringField(required=True)
    recordType = StringField(required=True)
    dataMap = DictField(required=True)
    priority = IntField()
    count = IntField()
    valid = BooleanField(required=True)
```